# XSLT Error with output String manipulation

Tags: xslt

I have create an XSLT that looks for the month tag in the following input and splits the string and creates new tags for each. However the issue i am having is that it is only looking at the first month tag and for any subsiquent `<set>` tags it auto fills them with the result from the first set.

So for this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8"?>
 <Response xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">
     <payload>
         <sets>
             <month>JUN,JUL</month>
             <season>Season11</season>
             <productId>1111111</productId>
         </sets>
         <sets>
            <month>AUG,SEP</month>
            <season>Season12</season>
            <productId>2222222</productId>
        </sets> 
    </payload>
</Response>
```

It **SHOULD** produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">
    <payload xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response">
        <sets>
            <month>JUN</month>
            <season>Season11</season>
            <productId>1111111</productId>
        </sets>
        <sets>
            <month>JUL</month>
            <season>Season11</season>
            <productId>1111111</productId>
        </sets>
        <sets>
            <month>AUG</month>
            <season>Season12</season>
            <productId>2222222</productId>
        </sets>
        <sets>
            <month>SEP</month>
            <season>Season12</season>
            <productId>2222222</productId>
        </sets>
    </payload>
</Response>
```

However its **ACTUAL** Response is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">
    <payload xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response">
        <sets>
            <month>JUN</month>
            <season>Season11</season>
            <productId>1111111</productId>
        </sets>
        <sets>
            <month>JUN</month>
            <season>Season12</season>
            <productId>2222222</productId>
        </sets>
        <sets>
            <month>JUL</month>
            <season>Season11</season>
            <productId>1111111</productId>
        </sets>
        <sets>
            <month>JUL</month>
            <season>Season12</season>
            <productId>2222222</productId>
        </sets>
    </payload>
</Response>
```

The current XSLT is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response" exclude-result-prefixes="r">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:param name="month"/>

        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="r:month">
        <xsl:param name="month"/>
        <month xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$month">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$month"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </month>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="splitMonths">
        <xsl:param name="months"/>
        <xsl:variable name="firstMonth" select="substring-before($months,',')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="month">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$firstMonth">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$firstMonth"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$months"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="otherMonths" select="substring-after($months,',')"/>
        <xsl:if test="$month">
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:with-param name="month" select="$month"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$otherMonths">
            <xsl:call-template name="splitMonths">
                <xsl:with-param name="months" select="$otherMonths"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="r:payload">

        <payload xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">

            <xsl:call-template name="splitMonths">
                <xsl:with-param name="months" select="r:sets/r:month"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </payload>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone help as i have been racking my brain around this one for days!

**UPDATE**

I was looking at the idea of looping through each `<sets>` tag and therefore use this section in the fill code above:

```
<xsl:template match="r:payload">
    <payload xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">
        <xsl:for-each select="r:sets">

        <xsl:call-template name="splitMonths">
            <xsl:with-param name="months" select="r:sets/r:month"/> 
        </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </payload>
</xsl:template>
```

However it produces the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Response xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response">
    <payload xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response">
        <month/>
        <season>SS11</season>
        <productId>3600596</productId>
        <month/>
        <season>AW12</season>
        <productId>7001258</productId>
    </payload>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pure XSLT 1.0 solution not needing any extension:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response"
  xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response"
  exclude-result-prefixes="r">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r:sets">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="r:month"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r:month">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, ','))">
        <sets>
          <month>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
          </month>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::r:month)]"/>
        </sets>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <sets>
          <month>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, ',')"/>
          </month>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::r:month)]"/>
        </sets>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ',')"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With XSLT 2.0 it is even easier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response"
  xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response"
  exclude-result-prefixes="r">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r:sets">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="r:month"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r:month">
    <xsl:param name="names" select="tokenize(., ',')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($names[2])">
        <sets>
          <month>
            <xsl:value-of select="$names[1]"/>
          </month>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::r:month)]"/>
        </sets>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <sets>
          <month>
            <xsl:value-of select="$names[1]"/>
          </month>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="../*[not(self::r:month)]"/>
        </sets>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="names" select="$names[position() gt 1]"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit] The XSLT 2.0 solution is modelled after the previous XSLT 1.0 solution but I think the following approach is more compact and easier to understand and execute:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.castiron.com/response"
  xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response"
  exclude-result-prefixes="r">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r:sets">
    <xsl:variable name="this-set" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(r:month, ',')">
      <sets>
        <month>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </month>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$this-set/*[not(self::r:month)]"/>
      </sets>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using a tokenizer and explicit matching, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:r="http://www.castiron.com/response"
  xmlns:s="http://exslt.org/strings"
  exclude-result-prefixes="r">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="*|r:*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="r:sets">
    <xsl:variable name="months" select="s:tokenize(r:month, ',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="*[name() != 'month']"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$months">
      <xsl:element name="sets" namespace="http://www.castiron.com/response">
        <xsl:element name="month" namespace="http://www.castiron.com/response">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- all the other children -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="$this"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: when i run this in oxygen i get the following error `The URL http://exslt.org/strings does not identify an external Java class` and then highlights this line `<xsl:variable name="months" select="s:tokenize(r:month,',')"/>`

Comment: I don't know what oxygen is, but it's an xslt extension, and there's source code for it, see http://www.exslt.org/str/index.html

Comment: maybe it works with the `extension-element-prefixes="s"` as they suggest

Comment: Keevil, as you mention Oxygen, does an XSLT 2.0 solution (which Oxygen supports with Saxon 9) suffice?

Comment: @martin honnen yes a version 2 solution would be sufficient yes.

Comment: @hroptatyr the problem i may have with that is i am using another tool called Cast Iron (ETL Tool) and it does not allow for any extensions that are not already included thus importing additoinal features which i think is what is needed for EXSLT. However it does look perfect for what i need.

Comment: Can you include stylesheets then?  There's an XSLT implementation of strings/tokenize on exslt's website.